# Capturing sent/recieved internet packets through Android

Tags: android, networking, network-monitor, packet-capture

I'm looking for an *Android* application that reveals (logs) the sent internet requests and received responses' headers of any Android application.

Comment: Afraid such an app does not exist. Not only did I never encounter any (check my profile at Android.SE to see if that statement has weight), but we had related issues at Android.SE many times in the last few years (e.g. how to find out which app accessed X), and never found a satisfying solution. Only thing I can name are [Network Sniffer](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_sniffspoof#group_389) – but with those you must know what you're looking for (not intended for "easy use by your grandma", if you know what I mean).